# Updating a column from a subquery on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns a,b and c.

Here is my scenario:

For every row in the table, I need to find `a="RECLASSEMENT CDS"`. From the result of this, I will get the column c and find all the same values `c=c` for the table and additional condition `b="GAP CDS"`. For the result of this, I will get the column `b`. I know this is confusing so I added a sample below.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_A
(A varchar(20) null,
B varchar(20) null,
C varchar(20) null)

INSERT #TEMP_A
VALUES
('RECLASSEMENT CDS', 'OLD TYPE', '123'),
('GAP CDS', 'NEW TYPE', '123'),   
('RECLASSEMENT CDS', 'DUMMY', '456')

UPDATE #TEMP_A SET A =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T3.A
    FROM #TEMP_A T1
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT C, A
        FROM #TEMP_A T2
        WHERE T2.C = T1.C
        AND T2.B = 'GAP CDS'
    ) T3
    WHERE 
    T1.B = 'RECLASSEMENT CDS'
    AND T1.C = T3.C
) WHERE B = 'RECLASSEMENT CDS'
```

On my data above, the first row's 2nd column should be replaced by the second row's 2nd column. But with my update statement above, even the third row is being replaced. Any ideas how I can implement this logic?

Comment: Rather than an `OUTER APPLY`, a `CROSS APPLY` seems like it would suit your purposes better (because presumably you don't want something in your table to be updated if it doesn't have a 'gap cds' value). But really, your whole query can be simplified to be less confusing. e.g. something like `UPDATE T SET A = T2.A FROM #TEMP_A T CROSS APPLY (SELECT A FROM #TEMP_A WHERE C = T.C AND A = 'GAP CDS') T2 WHERE T.A = 'RECLASSEMENT CDS'` unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, you probably don't even need a cross apply here. You can just do an update with an `EXISTS` clause. e.g. `UPDATE T SET A = 'GAP CDs' FROM #TEMP_A T WHERE T.A = 'RECLASSEMENT CDS' AND EXISTS (SELECT A FROM #TEMP_A WHERE C = T.C AND A='GAP CDS')`... Unless I'm still misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ZLK - The `cross apply` worked. I didn't try the `exists` yet. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved. And I doubt your query will run on both those dbms products.)